# No match for watch event 'sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchKey$Event@3f5ed469', path 'D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\logs\log_file.log'

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have setup **DCEVM + Hotswap** Agent on my local machine with tomcat and eclipse. I followed steps given at

- http://hotswapagent.org/mydoc_quickstart.html

i am using **jdk1.8.0_112** so i have downloaded **DCEVM-light-8u112-installer.jar** and patched my JVM using it.

when i start tomcat server in eclipse its giving below error

**HOTSWAP AGENT: 19:38:57.939 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.watch.nio.EventDispatcher) - No match for  watch event 'sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchKey$Event@3f5ed469',  path 'D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\logs\log_file.log'**

Answer (score 0):

Use version 1.3.0 (https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/releases/tag/RELEASE-1.3.0). This fixes the issue.